# VBA Word formatting Selection.typetext

Tags: vba, formatting, ms-word

I am still a beginner with this. Can you tell my why this is not formatting the selection?

```
Selection.TypeText "title"

With Selection

        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
End With
```

Answer (score 5):

It does format the text, but only text added *after* the `With Selection` command.

Change the order, put `Selection.TypeText "title"` last, and it will work. :)